# How to display an image in tkinter using grid

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to display an image to my GUI, through `PhotoImage`, however it is telling me that PhotoImage has no "grid" member.

I am using `.grid()` for all of my other widgets, like labels and buttons, so I can't use `.pack()`, if that would make a difference anyway. So, how could I display an image to my GUI with grids?

I don't know if code is necessary for this question, but

```py
# it works by getting a random image from a list of files
Label(root, text=f"Enter a number between one and {len(files)}")
self.entry = Entry(root)
self.entry.grid()
Button(root, text="Submit", command=self.getEntry).grid()
```

Then, getEntry() is:

```py
def getEntry(self):
    PhotoImage(name="",
     file=f{self.path}\\{self.showImage(self.entry.get())}).grid(row=1)
    """
    showImage() just returns the correct file 
    (e.g: files[index] where index is the input)
    """
```

Comment: is string formatting correct in original code? you have missed quotation : `f"{self.path....`

Comment: Yeah, that was a copying error, sorry!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NOTE:
 `grid()` is returning NoneValue, which means that your variable 'file' will be `NoneValue`.

To display an image in tkinter you'll need to do something like:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open(image_path)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

label = Label(root, image = photo)
label.image = photo
label.grid(row=1)
# label.pack()
```

#### NOTE:

> The PhotoImage class can read GIF and PGM/PPM images from files:

```
photo = PhotoImage(file="image.gif")

photo = PhotoImage(file="lenna.pgm")
```

> If you need to work with other file formats, the **Python Imaging
>   Library (PIL)** contains classes that lets you load images in over 30
>   formats, and convert them to Tkinter-compatible image objects:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

image = Image.open("lenna.jpg")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

> You can use a PhotoImage instance everywhere Tkinter accepts an image
>   object.

An example:

```
label = Label(image=photo)
label.image = photo # keep a reference!
label.pack()
```

You must keep a reference to the image object in your Python program, either by storing it in a global variable, or by attaching it to another object.

Comment: I don't have a PIL module. Any help?

Comment: just install it from cmd : pip install Pillow

Comment: The image isn't actually displaying, it's just a big gap.

Comment: You have to use a widget that can support images, after that use pack or grid

Answer (score 0):

You have to use a widget that can support images. Typically a label, but button can also configure a button to show an image, as well as add images to text and canvas widgets.